# Два алгоритма работают за O(n)

Tags: алгоритм

Меня срезали на тесте на этом вопросе, но я никак не могу вникнуть в суть.

Вопрос звучал так

**Два алгоритма работают за O(n) времени. Выберите верное утверждение**

1 - Оба алгоритма работают за одинаковое количество секунд
2 - Либо первый алгоритм работает всегда быстрее, либо второй
3 - Иногда первый может отработать быстрее, иногда второй, иногда одинаково

Я ответил 1 - и оказался не прав

В условии ничего не сказано ни про комплектацию, ни про процессы.

O(n) - это же линейная асимптотика. Пока все элементы циклом не переберутся ничего не поменяется

Comment: Ну, *обычно* пункт 2. Но возможен и п.3. П.1 - практически невозможно. Но вы с таким количеством однотипных вопросов не хотите для начала почитать учебник?...

Comment: O(n) ничего не говорит о времени выполнения. Оно говорит только о зависимости времени выполнения от n. Один алгоритм может обрабатывать 1 элемент за 1 мс, а второй за 2мс. Но при этом оба на 2 элемента тратить в 2 раза больше времени, вот они оба O(n). Так что я бы выбрал второй вариант.

Comment: Да вот я уже психую. Книгу Грокаем алгоритмы прочитал 2 раза, и 7!! раз пересмотрел урок.(((

Comment: Первые два ответа категоричны, третий говорит про "может". Я за третий. Ситуация из третьего возможна.

Comment: Третий должен быть. Линейная зависимость - это `C0 + C1*N`. Первая константа влияет при малых N, так что алгоритм c примерными константами `99 + 10*N` сначала отстаёт от `10 + 99*N`, потом обгоняет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Линейная сложность означает что алгоритм работает за время примерно равное `CN`. Время работы двух разных алгоритмов будет примерно `C1 * N`, `C2 * N`. `C1` и `C2` - положительные константы зависящие от алгоритма и обрудования.

Ответ `1` не подходит: если `C1` и `C2` будут заметно разные, времена работы тоже будут разные.

Ответ `2` не подходит если `C1` и `С2` примерно равны, то вы не можете сказать что один алгоритм быстрее другого.

Ответ `3` тоже не подходит. Вернее он подходит, но только если `C1` и `С2` примерно равны. Тогда алгоритмы будут работать примерно одно время. А так как "примерно" то возможно что "Иногда первый может отработать быстрее, иногда второй, иногда одинаково".

Что в голове у автора задачи было не скажу. Возможно имелся в виду третий ответ - в нём одном есть слово "может".

Comment: Плюсую третий ответ )

Answer (score 0):

Я за 3-й вариант.

- 1 - *Оба алгоритма работают за одинаковое количество секунд* - у нас нет такой гарантии, `O(n)` гарантирует только что время работы обоих алгоритмов *линейно* зависит от `n`, но не гарантирует, что это время одинаковое
- 2 - *Либо первый алгоритм работает всегда быстрее, либо второй* - опять же `O(n)` не гарантирует, что время конкретное и не говорит ничего о коэффициенте, на который нужно умножать `n`, и время работы алгоритма может зависеть от данных, ничто не мешает тому, чтобы на одних данных работал быстрее первый алгоритм, а на каких-то другой, при этом они оба всё-равно будут `O(n)`
- 3 - *Иногда первый может отработать быстрее, иногда второй, иногда одинаково* - а вот это утверждение как-раз не накладывает никаких ограничений и оно, кстати, могло бы быть справедливо для любого `O`, если про `n` тут ничего не говорится, я ставлю на этот вариант. Вот если бы говорилось, что при увеличении `n` один из алгоритмов оказывался бы строго быстрее другого, то тут можно было бы сказать, что `O` у этих алгоритмов должно было быть разным (например, `O(n)` и `O(n^2)`).